# Use record from one conditional split output in another conditional split output in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have source flat file which has two rows with below columns

```
Recordtype contractnumber
NTE        123
ITM        null
```

There are only two record types NTE and ITM. I have to write these records to two different destination files based on record type ie NTE will be written to the NTE file and ITM will be written to ITM file.
I’m using conditional split in ssis package to split these two rows.
Now the problem is, contract number for ITM is always going to be null so I want to map NTE row’s contract number to ITM line. But as I’m already separating the rows using conditional split, I’m not sure how can I get the contract number from NTE line in ITM line. Please let me know how this could be achieved.

I’m unable to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

A Conditional Split does not affect the availability of columns within that row.  Assume there was a third column "Col3" and it had values of 1 and 2 for your sample data.

The row will be able to access the value of Col3 regardless of whether it's in the NTE or ITM stream.

What you are asking for, is something different. You are asking for the ability to look back at a previous row for a value and that is not an out of the box capability of SSIS.

- Current row = yes
- Previous/Next row = no

Assuming the full file looks something like

```
Recordtype contractnumber
NTE        123
ITM        null
NTE        234
ITM        null
NTE        345
ITM        null
NTE        456
ITM        null
```

and you want output files like
NTE File

```
Recordtype contractnumber
NTE        123
NTE        234
NTE        345
NTE        456
```

ITM file

```
Recordtype contractnumber
ITM        123
ITM        234
ITM        345
ITM        456
```

You'll have to write an Script Component to do this.

You'll need to provide the ContractNumber as a read/write column.

Basic logic will be

1. Create a class variable of type string called PreviousContractNumber and initialize it to the empty string
2. In the OnPipelineRowsSent or whatever the per row code block is called, you'll need to test whether the contractnumber's _IsNull property is true. In that case, you'll update it with the member variable PreviousContractNumber. If it is not null, then you'll need to update PreviousContractNumber to be the current row's contractnumber.

Add this component after your source component and before the Conditional Split.